# How to find the back-end artifact of a Jenkins plugin? Is it stored in Nexus? Just need the path of the artifacts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I was trying to access Jenkins Stage View pipeline plugin's temporary files/artifacts, couldn't find the exact location.

Comment: Hi there, please let us know what you have exactly tried to do in order to access the files.

Comment: Are you looking for the plugin file itself?  The hpi/jpi file?  Those are stored in the ${JENKINS_HOME}\plugins directory